# The text of an error is not red

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following html output:

```
<div class="clearfix has-error">
    <label for="id_password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password" type="password">
    <span class="help-inline">This field is required</span>
  </div>
```

The inputBox itself and its title (label) are red but the error text is not. According to the documentation it should be. I wonder why and how do I fix this?

Twitter bootstrap 3.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `class="help-inline"` with `class="help-block"`.

It should be something like:

```
<span class="help-block">This field is required</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think u are looking for this

```
<div class="clearfix has-error">
    <label for="id_password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password" type="password">
    <span class="help-block">This field is required</span>
  </div>
```

This will add red color to text. Instead of .help-inline add .help-block class.